# How JavaScript automatic cast works?

Tags: javascript

I try some things to learn how the language works and I just test this:

```js
console.log(2 + '3') // Print "23"
console.log(2 * '3') // Print 6
```

If in the first case the answer is `"23"` my attempts was that the answer for the second case should be `"33"` like in python.
But the second case returns `6` so I tell me why the first case do not return `5`
What is the rule ?

Comment: The first line overloads `+` operator, when a string is one of the operands of the "increment", `+` is considered as a string concatenator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `+`, or addition operator in the code below, is used to add numbers (both whole numbers and decimals) or concatenate strings.

According to https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascriptss-addition-operator-demystified/ the conversion rules of using the `+` (addition operator) are (when adding `operand + operand = result` for example):

1. If at least one operand is an object, it is converted to a primitive value (string, number or boolean);
2. After conversion, if at least one operand is string type, the second operand is converted to string and the concatenation is executed;
3. In other case both operands are converted to numbers and arithmetic addition is executed.

So because the code below is a number (first operand), `+` (addition operator), and string (second operand) then the number (`2`) converts to a string (`'2'`) and the two strings are concatenated together (`'23'`).

```
console.log(2 + '3') // Print "23"
```

For the multiplication operator (`*`) there is only a type conversion if a string can be converted into a number, like the code below, or even `2 * '1.5' // Print 3`.

Furthermore, if you try to do something like `2 * 'blah'` where the string 'blah' can't be converted into a number, then you get `NaN` (not a number) which is still a type of number (typeof `NaN // Print "number"`).

So the multiplication operator (`*`) between two or more operands always results in a `"number"` type, or `NaN` value which is still a `"number"` type.

```
console.log(2 * '3') // Print 6
```

Comment: Thank you, very clear, the link explains everything :)

Answer (score 1):

When you add a string and a number, the number is converted to a string and a joined string is returned.

Multiplication tries to convert operands to numbers and return a result.

```
'12.2' * '2' is 24.4
'12.2' * 'foo' is NaN
```

In any case, you shouldn't rely on this or write such code.

Comment: Thank you, of course, it's just to understand the functioning ;)